# UAC impersonation and unit tests

Tags: unit-testing, winapi, uac

I have some setup functions that require admin privileges the results of which are consumed by another application that does not run elevated. So for my unit tests to really reflect reality I need to call the setup functions then drop elevation somehow so I can call the functions that consume the setup. Is there no reasonably easy way to do that? It looks like I ought to be able to use

CreateRestrictedToken

and

ImpersonateLoggedOnUser

Any examples out there?

Answer (score 0):

UAC elevation is performed only at process startup.  It is not possible to (de)elevation a process once it has started running.  So, to do what you are attempting, you need separate processes.  You can either:

1. run your .exe initially non-elevated and have it start a new elevated process when it needs to call the setup functions.  The non-elevated process can use `ShellExecute/Ex()` with the `"runas"` verb, or use the third-party [`CreateProcessElevated()`](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vista-security/UAC__The_Definitive_Guide.aspx) implementation, to start the new process in an elevated state.
2. run your .exe initially elevated and have it call the setup functions, then use `CreateRestrictedToken()` and `CreateProcessAsUser()` to start a separate non-elevated process when it needs to call the consumer functions.
3. move the setup functions into a COM object, then run the .exe in a non-elevated state and have it instantiate the COM object in an elevated state using the [COM Elevation Moniker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679687.aspx) when it needs to call the setup functions.

For #1 and #2, for easy management, you could have all of the code in a single .exe file that just run a new copy of itself passing it a command-line parameter that tells it which functions to call and then exit immediately.